# Column Change When Responsive - Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to ask how can I make a `<div>` from `class="col-6"` at desktop mode and make it full column `col-12` at mobile view?

For my first though I try to make it something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-xs-12">
            Content goes here...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I go to `Inspect > Mobile View` I thought it going to make it full column but it is not.

So there's a second choice for me to do it, which is:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <!-- Content on Desktop -->
        <div class="col-6 hidden-mobile">
            Content goes here...
        </div>

        <!-- Content on Mobile -->
        <div class="col-12 hidden-desktop">
            Content goes here...
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any possible way to make it without duplicate 2 content div?

Comment: Pergh orang malaysia wowowo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you try ??
You can use the new "small" grid classes (col-sm-*) to prevent the layout from stacking on smaller display.

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
                 Content goes here...
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-9">

                <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
                      Content goes here...
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
                      Content goes here...
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

see here [demo](https://www.bootply.com/71450#)
If you want it to never stack, even on the smallest displays, use the tiny col-xs-* grid classes

Comment: You solve my problem! But why is it `col-lg-3` and `col-sm-3` but not `col-lg-3` and `col-sm-12`? I thought it going to full 12 column when it goes to small screen?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should give link of bootstrap stylesheets.
and secondly you need to use col-md-6 as well.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="setest_style.css">
  <!-- Site CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that I'm using bootstrap 4. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Bootstrap 4 to do this?

In Bootstrap 4 `-xs` infix is removed from those classes. Visit here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#global-changes

Bootstrap 4 is mobile first so You should follow it as below

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            Content goes here...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Helo. Sorry that I din't mention that I'm using bootstrap 4. Your method is also able to make the column to full width. But when it go back to desktop view it make them 3 content turn into each row.

Comment: 3 content turn? why? I'm sure If you want to do 2 column in a row you only need class `col-sm-6`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            Content goes here...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```
mean when viewport device > 576px is full width and < 576px is 2 column

I think this will be your html structure is clean and semantic

Comment: When you use any -sm-*, -md-*, default it's going return full width when it goes to small screen.